# Adjusting zoom level based size of features in layered PDF using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, pdf, illustrator

I have multiple layers in QGIS, consisting of dots, of which I have made a layered PDF. The problem I encountered is concerning the size of the dots when zooming

When in QGIS they adjust perfectly, and they stay the same size the entire time. (So when I zoom in, they get smaller relative to the map but stay the same size relative to the screen) When I create a layered pdf (Using Illustrator) this attribute seems to disappear entirely. They start at the same size, but the dots just stay that way the entire time, no matter the zoom level.

I know using a layered PDF is asking for problems, but I just have to do it this way.

I'm using QGIS 3.22.3.

Comment: Why are you creating a layered PDF with illustrator instead of using the built in export?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the build-in export, but it's important that the layers can be turned on/off. Is this also possible when using the build-in export?

Comment: Yes, it is. What else would be the purpose of layers?

Comment: I just tried to export it directly with the built-in module. But with no success. I can't switch layers on or off. The dots are also still not resizing.

Comment: I think that object changing size when zooming is the expected behaviour in a PDF (the whole point of zooming is to get thing to display bigger or smaller). It different than changing scale in a GIS software where you can set the size of object to be the same at all scale. So your problem may come from object getting to small or to big to see when you zoom

Comment: To get layers in the pdf you need to check the Create Geospatial PDF box.  But having layers in a pdf won't show the same scaling you get in QGIS.  You could create multiple layers with different symbol/label sizes for different scales to replace one layer, and then turn each off or on at different scales as a rough workaround.